# Pivot only certain values in a column

Tags: python, pandas, reshape

I have dataframes like this (the number of key_ is always equal to the number of value_, but this number is not known in advance):

```
    firstid    secondid    key_1    key_2    key_3    ...    key_n    value_1    value_2    value_3    ...    value_n
      1          one         A        B        C       ...    Z        alpha    beta          gamma    ...    omega
```

I would like to reshape them into this format:

```
first_id    second_id    key    value
1             one         A    alpha
1             one         B    beta
1             one         C    gamma
1             one         ...    ...
1             one         Z    omega
```

By using `melt` like this...

```
value_vars = [x for x in df.columns if x.startswith('key_') or x.startswith('value_')]

df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=["firstid",
                            "secondid"],
              value_vars=value_vars)
```

...I get this result:

```
   firstid secondid variable  value
0        1      one    key_1      A
1        1      one    key_2      B
2        1      one    key_3      C
3        1      one    key_n      Z
4        1      one  value_1  alpha
5        1      one  value_2   beta
6        1      one  value_3  gamma
7        1      one  value_n   omega
```

It clearly remains a step, but I cannot figure out which one in the jungle of melt, pivot, stack, etc. Any explanation or clue would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need:

- first [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for all columns with no `_`
- create `MultiIndex` in columns by [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html)
- reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)
- data cleaning by double [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

---

```
df = df.set_index(['firstid','secondid'])
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df = df.stack().reset_index(level=2, drop=True).reset_index()
print (df)
   firstid secondid key  value
0        1      one   A  alpha
1        1      one   B   beta
2        1      one   C  gamma
3        1      one   Z   zeta
```

Comment: The result is perfect, thank you so much! I do not understand everything you did, so I will not be able to do it again by myself, but I know at least what functions I need to bone up.

Comment: Congratulations on 200k :)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - Thank you. ;)